# Difference of affine varities $\mathbb V(xz,yz)-\mathbb V(z)$ not variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Consider the ideal $V_1:=\mathbb V(xz,yz)$, xy -plane union z -axis, and $\mathbb V(z)$, z -axis. Now the difference $\mathbb V_1-\mathbb V(z)$ equals to $z$ -axis with origin moved. The z-axis is the smalles variety containing $V_{not}:=\mathbb V_2-\mathbb V(z)$. Variety is defined such that

> Let $k$ be a field, and let $f_1,\ldots ,f_s$ be polynomials in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. Then 
>   $$\mathbb V(f_1,\ldots,f_s) = \{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in k^n : f_i(a_1,\ldots,a_n) = 0 \forall 1\leq i\leq s\}.$$ We call $V(f_1,\ldots,f_s)$ the affine variety defined by $f_1,\ldots,f_s$.

Please explain why this $V_{not}$ is not a variety.

*P.s. Studying the book Ideals, Varities, and Algorithms by Cox et all (2008, 3rd edition): the example given in introduction Ch1 and then this observation related to Zariski closure, elimination and quotients ~Ch3.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a (closed) variety simply because it is not the zero locus of a collection of polynomials. Given two varieties $V(f_1,\dots,f_m),V(g_1,\dots,g_n)$, the union and intersection is a variety because the union is the zero locus of the products $V(f_i g_j)$ and the intersection is the zero locus of both sets of polynomials $V(f_1,\dots,f_m, g_1, \dots g_n)$. We cannot in general define the set *difference* as a zero locus. $V_{\text{not}}$ is however an open subset of a variety, so it is a quasiaffine variety as they are called.

Comment: +1 and accepted because of the topological explanation with zero locus. I find it convenient method to consider varieties with open sets and closed sets. Thank you for explaining algebraic concepts in terms of topology :)

Comment: I suspected this would clarify things. Still, to prove that this particular set is not a locus we need to use some argument similar to MooS's: We can think of the $z$ axis as the affine line $\mathbb{A}^1$ and for a polynomial $f \in k[x,y,z]$ we can set $x,y = 0$ to get a polynomial in $k[z]$. Then any polynomial that is zero on $\mathbb{A}^1\setminus \{ 0 \}$ must be the zero polynomial since it has infinitely many roots (here $k = \mathbb{A}^1$ is infinite since we assume $k$ is algebraically closed). This implies that $0$ is in the (zariski) closure of $\mathbb{A}^1\setminus\{ 0 \}$

Answer (score 4):

If $k$ is a finite field, your set is indeed a variety. If $k$ is infinite,

let $\{(0,0,z) ~|~ z \neq 0\} \subset V(f_1, \dotsc, f_s)$, i.e. $f_i(0,0,z)=0$ for any  $z \in k\setminus \{0\}$. Since $k$ is infinite, this shows that $f_i(0,0,z) \in k[z]$ is the zero-polynomial, i.e. we have $f(0,0,0)=0$. This shows that $(0,0,0)$ is a point of $V(f_1, \dotsc, f_s)$, hence $\{(0,0,z) ~|~ z \neq 0\}$ is not an affine variety.

If the field happens to be $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, we can shorten the argument and just notice that any affine variety is closed with respect to the euclidean topology.

Comment: On *"Since $k$ is infinite, this shows that $f_i(0,0,z)\in k[z]$ is the zero-polynomial, i.e. we have $f(0,0,0)=0$."*: can you explain that somehow z is 0 here in contrast to the beginning where *"-- for any $z\in k\backslash \{0\}$"* (z not zero)?

Comment: @hhh: This is by Proposition 5 of Chapter 1 of the book you are reading. In an infinite field $k$, if a polynomial $f\in k[x]$ has infinitely many zeros, it is the zero-polynomial.

Comment: @KittyL thank you, I formulated the reason like this in mind bf recalling this:  $f$ is zero polynomial in infinite field IFF it must also be zero function. This is extremely counterintuitive result, +1 for this observation :)

Comment: How is this result counterintuitive?

Comment: @hhh: I actually think it is much more intuitive than the finite case.:)

Comment: @MooS let $k^n\backslash \{\mathbf 0\}$ be an infinite field having no zeros $x_i\not = 0$ and the zero function $f=0$. By Proposition 5, $f:k^n\mapsto k$ zero function for all values of $\mathbf x$ in $k^n$. Now this also means $\mathbf 0$ values even though they are not in the infinite field. [Relevant](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656515/difference-of-affine-varities-mathbb-vxz-yz-mathbb-vz-not-variety/1656531?noredirect=1#comment3378478_1656531): I may be mixing the concept about zero locus (z=0 in above infinite case so closed) to this new case $\mathbf 0\not\in k^n, f=0$.